# Multiple monitors and Java applets

Tags: java, applet, resolution, multiple-monitors

Is there a way for Java applet to detect on which monitor it is currently displayed, in case of multi-monitor setup? Basically I need to know the screen resolution of the monitor which shows my java applet.
Any ideas?

Comment: You could get the screen resolution with javascript and pass the values to the applet

Comment: Yes, I thought about JS two, but I was wondering if pure Java solution exists. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myApplet.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds()
```

Should return a Rectangle holding the resolution of the screen that the Applet is on.

JavaDocs for [GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getBounds%28%29).

Comment: Great! It seams that getGraphicsConfiguration() actually returns current GraphicsConfiguration of the screen where applet is shown, and not the one it was initially create on. Thanks!